# Updating and accessing parent variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating tic-tac-toe in JavaScript, and I'm trying to keep track of which player's turn it is in a variable called `currentPlayer`. This variable is declared at the top of the script and assigned the value of 1, for player 1. It is then accessed and updated within the function renderBoard.

After player 1 makes a move, I call a renderBoard function, which renders the newest move and then sets the currentPlayer variable to 2 to indicate that it's now player 2's turn. After the function finishes, I output some HTML that uses `currentPlayer` to show that it's player 2's turn. However, in my code `currentPlayer` is not being recognized as being set to 2.

Here's the code:

```
var currentPlayer = 1;
// Other code

function renderBoard(newMove, currentPlayer)
{
    if(!gameOver){
        if(currentPlayer === 1)
        {
            $(newMove).append('<img src="assets/x.png" />');
            currentPlayer = 2;
        } else
        {
            $(newMove).append('<img src="assets/o.png" />');
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
    } else
    {
        $('img').remove();
    }
}

    $('#gameboard-wrapper').on(
        'click',
        'div[data-location]',
        function() 
        {
            renderBoard(this, currentPlayer);
            $('p').html("Player " + currentPlayer + "'s turn"); // After player 1's move, this should output 2, but it repeatedly outputs 1.*/
            $(this).off();
        }
    );
```

As far as I understand it, the currentPlayer is a global variable and should be updated for the entire script, even though it's updated inside of a function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for anyone looking at this question in the future.

My mistake was making a currentPlayer parameter for the renderBoard function. When I was referencing currentPlayer, I was referencing the currentPlayer argument that was passed when the function was called, and not the currentPlayer global variable.

Corrected code:

```
var currentPlayer = 1;
// Other code

function renderBoard(newMove) // Removed currentPlayer parameter
{
    if(!gameOver){
        if(currentPlayer === 1)
        {
            $(newMove).append('<img src="assets/x.png" />');
            currentPlayer = 2;
        } else
        {
            $(newMove).append('<img src="assets/o.png" />');
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
    } else
    {
    $('img').remove();
    }
}

$('#gameboard-wrapper').on(
    'click',
    'div[data-location]',
    function() 
    {
        renderBoard(this); // Don't pass in currentPlayer argument
        $('p').html("Player " + currentPlayer + "'s turn");
        $(this).off();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You call (this).off. It takes off the click interface. After that nothing happens when you click the game. Remove this.off.

Comment: $(this).off() removes the event handler on the element (corresponding to a game board space) just clicked. I don't want a player in the future to be able to make more than one move on a single space, so I remove the event handler altogether from that space.

Comment: According to jquery: The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed. Are you sure the game is still moving after the first move?

Comment: Have you wrote current player to console so you can check if events are still firing?

Comment: You're right, just tested it and it didn't work. I removed it as you suggested and just added an additional conditional to the renderBoard function to make sure the space hadn't been selected yet.

Comment: One thing I would have done is have location as class instead of data attribute. Then you can say $(".location").on...blah blah then when you say $(this).off you would be talking about that play square and not the whole board.